# Lists of Keywords for RMM

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

I am implementing Reply Mail Management and I am not able to create custom keywords under the 'Reply Mail Management' section. In my account, the 'Keywords Lists' do not appear.

I have the Enterprise 2.0 account.

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted (by clicking on the checkmark icon left of it) so others can easily identify this as being solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom Keyword Lists are only available for "Enterprise Reply Mail Management" - which isn't directly tied to the License/Account type you have and always needs to be activated by Salesforce on request.

In order to activate this feature to make use of the Keyword Lists, you just need to log a support case and ask for activation of "Enterprise Reply Mail Management".

Before doing so I suggest you make yourself familiar with the entire feature by reading the documentation and also note that a triggered send is always required for the forward even though the documentation says otherwise.

For more information regarding this feature and all available configuration options please also see the [Enterprise RMM documentation pages.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_enterprise_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5)